# Keycloak - Custom form action not visible in flow

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to implement custom form action for user registration. I have added few custom fields on the form and I wish to validate those fields. After going through the keycloak documentation, I realised that I need to

- Extend FormAction, FormActionFactory
- Package the actionfactory in META-INF/services/org.keycloak.authentication.FormActionFactory
- Deploy the JAR in keycloak/standalone/deployments folder.

I have done all the steps and verified that the provider is getting loaded. Here is the log from keycloak log file

```
15:35:29,962 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 46) KC-SERVICES0047: organization-field-validation-action (com.phoenix.keycloak.forms.action.OrganizationFormAction) is implementing the internal SPI form-action. This SPI is internal and may change without notice
```

But when I go to Authentication execution screen, the provider is not listed.
[image]

Here is the code for custom action.

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com.phoenix.keycloak.forms.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap;

import org.keycloak.Config.Scope;
import org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction;
import org.keycloak.authentication.FormActionFactory;
import org.keycloak.authentication.FormContext;
import org.keycloak.authentication.ValidationContext;
import org.keycloak.events.Details;
import org.keycloak.events.Errors;
import org.keycloak.forms.login.LoginFormsProvider;
import org.keycloak.models.AuthenticationExecutionModel.Requirement;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSession;
import org.keycloak.models.KeycloakSessionFactory;
import org.keycloak.models.RealmModel;
import org.keycloak.models.UserModel;
import org.keycloak.models.utils.FormMessage;
import org.keycloak.provider.ProviderConfigProperty;
import org.keycloak.services.validation.Validation;

/**
 * @author Yogesh Jadhav
 *
 */
public class OrganizationFormAction implements FormAction, FormActionFactory {

    private static final String PROVIDER_ID = "organization-field-validation-action";

    private static Requirement[] REQUIREMENT_CHOICES = { Requirement.REQUIRED, Requirement.DISABLED };

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.Provider#close()
     */
    @Override
    public void close() {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.ProviderFactory#create(org.keycloak.models.
     * KeycloakSession)
     */
    @Override
    public FormAction create(KeycloakSession arg0) {
        return this;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.ProviderFactory#getId()
     */
    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return PROVIDER_ID;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.ProviderFactory#init(org.keycloak.Config.Scope)
     */
    @Override
    public void init(Scope arg0) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.ProviderFactory#postInit(org.keycloak.models.
     * KeycloakSessionFactory)
     */
    @Override
    public void postInit(KeycloakSessionFactory arg0) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory#getDisplayType()
     */
    @Override
    public String getDisplayType() {
        return "Organization Profile Validation";
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.authentication.ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory#
     * getReferenceCategory()
     */
    @Override
    public String getReferenceCategory() {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.authentication.ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory#
     * getRequirementChoices()
     */
    @Override
    public Requirement[] getRequirementChoices() {
        return REQUIREMENT_CHOICES;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory#isConfigurable()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isConfigurable() {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.authentication.ConfigurableAuthenticatorFactory#
     * isUserSetupAllowed()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isUserSetupAllowed() {
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.ConfiguredProvider#getConfigProperties()
     */
    @Override
    public List<ProviderConfigProperty> getConfigProperties() {
        return null;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.provider.ConfiguredProvider#getHelpText()
     */
    @Override
    public String getHelpText() {
        return "Validates organization name and mobile number field.";
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction#buildPage(org.keycloak.authentication.
     * FormContext, org.keycloak.forms.login.LoginFormsProvider)
     */
    @Override
    public void buildPage(FormContext arg0, LoginFormsProvider arg1) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction#configuredFor(org.keycloak.models.
     * KeycloakSession, org.keycloak.models.RealmModel,
     * org.keycloak.models.UserModel)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean configuredFor(KeycloakSession arg0, RealmModel arg1, UserModel arg2) {
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction#requiresUser()
     */
    @Override
    public boolean requiresUser() {
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction#setRequiredActions(org.keycloak.models
     * .KeycloakSession, org.keycloak.models.RealmModel,
     * org.keycloak.models.UserModel)
     */
    @Override
    public void setRequiredActions(KeycloakSession arg0, RealmModel arg1, UserModel arg2) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction#success(org.keycloak.authentication.
     * FormContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void success(FormContext arg0) {
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see
     * org.keycloak.authentication.FormAction#validate(org.keycloak.authentication.
     * ValidationContext)
     */
    @Override
    public void validate(ValidationContext context) {
        MultivaluedMap<String, String> formData = context.getHttpRequest().getDecodedFormParameters();
        List<FormMessage> errors = new ArrayList<>();

        context.getEvent().detail(Details.REGISTER_METHOD, "form");
        String eventError = Errors.INVALID_REGISTRATION;

        if (Validation.isBlank(formData.getFirst("user.attributes.companyName"))) {
            errors.add(new FormMessage("user.attributes.companyName", "missingOrganizationNameMessage"));
        }

        if (Validation.isBlank(formData.getFirst("user.attributes.contactPersonMobile"))) {
            errors.add(new FormMessage("user.attributes.contactPersonMobile", "missingContactPersonMobileMessage"));
        }

        if (errors.size() > 0) {
            context.error(eventError);
            context.validationError(formData, errors);
            return;

        } else {
            context.success();
        }
    }

}
```

Not able to figure out what went wrong here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apologies. I was looking at the wrong "Add Execution" option. I realized that each form also has a corresponding "Actions" menu. This menu also has "Add Execution" option.

[image]

After selecting that option, I could see my Custom Form action is displayed in the restricted list of actions.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to accept terms and conditions per client.
Do you think it could be done using this approach or is it necessary to extend RequiredActionFactory? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62758864

Comment: @user60108 yes you should ideally be using RequiredActionFactory. Thats the ideal way to go for your requirement.